# onload event in programmatically added attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Why the onload event not triggered when elements are added in the following code:

```js
function create() {
var para = document.createElement("p");     

para.setAttribute('onload', 'myFunction');

var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);


}

function myFunction() {
  alert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="create()">create</button>
```

Is this not the proper way to set an attribute on an element or is the problem that the onload function is not fired?

Comment: because `HTMLParagraphElement` doesn't fire `onload` event.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Ow didn't realize that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
function create() {
var para = document.createElement("p");

var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

para.onload = myFunction();

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);


}

function myFunction() {
  alert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="create()">create</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```js
function create() {
var para = document.createElement("p");     

$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', para, myFunction());
//para.setAttribute('onload', 'myFunction');

var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);


}

function myFunction() {
  alert(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="create()">create</button>
```